# python pandas: Simplest way to perform group by and extract count of unique entities?

Tags: python, pandas, count, group-by, unique

my df:

```
nr,name
1,sam
2,sam
1,mar
1,sam
2,tom
2,jack
1,mar
```

How can I group by 'nr' and count distinct names in 'name' column? this must be a very easy command in all languages like mysql(groupby and distinct command) but I cannot find this in pandas. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `nunique()`

```
In [13]: df.groupby('nr')['name'].nunique()
Out[13]:
nr
1     2
2     3
```

Alternatively, use `pd.Series.nunique`

```
In [14]: df.groupby('nr').agg({'name': pd.Series.nunique})
Out[14]:
    name
nr
1      2
2      3
```

Also, you could use `nunique()` in `agg()`

```
In [15]: df.groupby('nr').agg({'name': lambda x: x.nunique()})
Out[15]:
    name
nr
1      2
2      3
```

Interestingly, at times, I noticed `len(x.unique())` is much faster than above methods.

```
In [16]: df.groupby('nr').agg({'name': lambda x: len(x.unique())})
Out[16]:
    name
nr
1      2
2      3
```

Answer (score 3):

You want [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nunique.html#pandas.Series.nunique):

```
In [4]:

df.groupby('nr')['name'].nunique()
Out[4]:
nr
1    2
2    3
Name: name, dtype: int64
```

So this returns the number of unique values for that column grouped by 'nr'